# GIT 2nd PUSH is failing

Tags: git, github

I am new to git.

I am trying to push my new code into remote repository using `git push origin master`. But it is failing with below error:

```
To git@gitlab.unique.com:uniquedata-analytics/TEST-SAS.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.unique.com:uniquedata-analytics/TEST-SAS.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried `git pull` before doing `git push`.

Still I am getting the same error.

I saw many such similar questions on stack, but of not much help. Any help is highly appreciated.

Do I need to perform any remote clone, and then add my files, then do the `push`.

Or I can just do a `git pull`, then add my files and then do a `push`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you've pulled?  That's what the error message is looking for you to do.

Comment: If `git pull` first doesn't do the trick, can you run `git status` and display the output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

Git will not allow you to push changes if our branch is not up to date with the server

Once you try to `push` your code to the remote repo git verify that your "local" branch has all the latest code from the remote branch. If it see that you are missing some commits it will not let you push the code to the remote.

---

#### How to fix it?

Its very simple - you simply need to pull the changes from the server in one of the following ways:

```
# assuming you are on the desired branch

# update your local server with all the latest code from the server
# This is an optional command but its a good practice to always be 
# synchronized with the server
git fetch --all --prune

# now pull (pull = fetch + merge) the changes from the server to your branch
git pull origin <branch name>

# now your local branch is up to date and contains all the "server" code as well

# push your changes to the remote branch
git push origin <branch name>
```

Comment: `git fetch` is redundant if you follow it with a `git pull`, which does its own fetch. Since you've just fetched, your next command should be `git merge origin/<branch_name>` (or `git rebase origin/<branch_name>`), not `git pull origin <branch name>`.

Comment: Agreed i mentioned it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You must perform another **git pull** since your local current branch is behind the remote one. Even that you've already performed a **git pull** doesn't block others to perform their own **git push** afterwards and before your next **git push**. This is a common git scenario.